# How do you prove if A ⊆ ∅, then A = ∅?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

To show that $A = \emptyset$,
We need to prove that $A \subseteq \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subseteq A$.

$\emptyset \subseteq A$ can be proven since the empty set is a subset of any set.

However, it still does not prove that "if $A \subseteq \emptyset$, then $A = \emptyset$". How do I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $B\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq B$ then $A=B$

Answer (score 3):

You have $A\subseteq\emptyset$ and $\emptyset\subseteq A$.  Therefore, $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: this is a classic approach to prove sets are equal

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $E\subseteq F$ implies that for every $e$, if $e\in E$ then we must have $e\in F$ as well.

Supposing that $A\subseteq \emptyset$ that implies that for every $a$, if $a\in A$ then we must have $a\in\emptyset$ as well.

It follows then that $A$ has no elements, since if there were such an $a$ such that $a\in A$ it would follow that $a\in \emptyset$, a contradiction as there are no elements in the empty set by definition.

Comment: So is it impossible for any set to be a subset of ∅? (e.g. A ⊆ ∅)

Comment: @CliffordTan It is impossible for any *non-empty* set to be a subset of $\emptyset$, but of course the emptyset is a subset of the emptyset.

Answer (score 0):

By definition
$$A = B \iff A \subseteq B \text{ and } B \subseteq A.$$
Note also that for any set $S$,
$x \in \emptyset \implies x \in S$ is vacuously true. Thus, $\emptyset \subseteq S$.

Therefore, $A = \emptyset$ since $A \subseteq \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subseteq A$.